# c++17: header only: class static variable errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, static-variables

Since C++17, I've been experimenting easier ways to get class static variables. I'm writing a header-only library. Apparently the new meaning of `inline` for variables is suited for this.

```
class thingy {
    static inline reporter rep;
};
```

But I've been getting runtime errors.

I'm using Visual Studio 15.6.4

To test, the following:

- `thingy` has a static member variable
- The member tells you when it's constructed / destructed and at what address
- Should be constructed and destructed exactly once
- Is #included in two .cpp files

**foo.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct reporter {
    reporter() {
        cout << "reporter() - " << this << endl;
    }
    ~reporter() {
        cout << "~reporter() - " << this << endl;
    }
};

class thingy {
    static inline reporter rep;
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
int main() {}
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
```

---

Most disappointingly, it prints:

```
reporter() - 00007FF670E47C80
reporter() - 00007FF670E47C80
~reporter() - 00007FF670E47C80
~reporter() - 00007FF670E47C80
```

As you can see, it is constructed twice and destructed twice at the same location - not good.

Am I misunderstanding what `inline` on variables is for?

Is there another way to get class statics in header only? Has this changed in C++17?

Comment: I don't see the behavior on [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/euAEPCEqSl0OSdxv) or [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PKAIMCcFKdjkOehp). Haven't tested MSVC, though. Probably a MSVC bug, but before you file it, definitely make sure you check the preview version

Comment: what is in the main function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a bug in VS2017.

A few relevant bug reports can be found, although they do not exactly meet your case:

- [VC2017 15.5.2 inline variable crashed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169305/vc2017-1552-inline-variable-crashed.html)
- [Local static variable initialized multiple times](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/195147/local-static-variable-initialized-multiple-times.html)

> **This will be addressed in 15.7** - thanks for the report!
>   Combining multiple guards for adjacent static variables into a single guard is a backend optimization which can go wrong when inlining under certain circumstances. That's basically the issue here.

Hopefully this *static variable when inline-ed* bug will be fixed soon in their next patch.

Meanwhile, I found that compiling in `Release Mode` makes your `reporter` initialized **only once** as expected, while in `Debug Mode` this bug occurs for their *backend optimization*.

So I guess this won't be going into your products, at least.

Comment: Seems like a fix is now available in the current preview version according to this bug report : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169305/vc2017-1552-inline-variable-crashed.html

You can download it here : https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in MSVC.

The static class member `thingy::rep`, like `thingy`, has [external linkage](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#4), the `inline` specifier doesn't change that.

As such, there can be only [one](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#2.1) instance of it in the whole program, and as such it can only be initialized once.

[[class.static.data]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#class.static.data-5):

> Static data members of a class in namespace scope have the linkage of that class.